# Where do these determinants come from for line intersection?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I was in need of a method to compute the intersection of two lines given two points along each line. While searching for such a method, I came across one on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection#Given_two_points_on_each_line) that listed the results from determinants. It however does not show how these determinants were derived. I would like to know how they were derived and not just blindly use the method without understanding it.

To clarify, I am not asking how the final version of $(P_{x}, P_{y})$ is derived; thats just the cross product of the determinants themselves. Rather, how did the original determinants come to be? What was the linear system when given 4 points, 2 for each line?

Comment: Essentially the two lines intersect if and only if they are not parallel. If we subtract the two points determining a line this gives a vector. For two lines to intersect, the two vectors must not be multiples of each other. This is true iff the $2\times 2$ determinant in the denominator is not zero.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt at the (usually inadvisable) approach of reverse-engineering the systems of equations from the solutions.  We have
$$
P_x  = 
\frac{\begin{vmatrix} \begin{vmatrix} x_1 & y_1\\x_2 & y_2\end{vmatrix} &  \begin{vmatrix} x_1 & 1\\x_2 & 1\end{vmatrix} \\\\ \begin{vmatrix} x_3 & y_3\\x_4 & y_4\end{vmatrix} & \begin{vmatrix} x_3 & 1\\x_4 & 1\end{vmatrix} \end{vmatrix} }
{\begin{vmatrix} \begin{vmatrix} x_1 & 1\\x_2 & 1\end{vmatrix} &  \begin{vmatrix} y_1 & 1\\y_2 & 1\end{vmatrix} \\\\ \begin{vmatrix} x_3 & 1\\x_4 & 1\end{vmatrix} & \begin{vmatrix} y_3 & 1\\y_4 & 1\end{vmatrix} \end{vmatrix}}
= 
- \frac{\begin{vmatrix} \begin{vmatrix} x_1 & 1\\x_2 & 1\end{vmatrix} & 
\begin{vmatrix} x_1 & y_1\\x_2 & y_2\end{vmatrix}
\\\\ 
 \begin{vmatrix} x_3 & 1\\x_4 & 1\end{vmatrix} & \begin{vmatrix} x_3 & y_3\\x_4 & y_4\end{vmatrix}\end{vmatrix} }
{\begin{vmatrix} \begin{vmatrix} x_1 & 1\\x_2 & 1\end{vmatrix} &  \begin{vmatrix} y_1 & 1\\y_2 & 1\end{vmatrix} \\\\ \begin{vmatrix} x_3 & 1\\x_4 & 1\end{vmatrix} & \begin{vmatrix} y_3 & 1\\y_4 & 1\end{vmatrix} \end{vmatrix}}
$$
and
$$
P_y = \frac{\begin{vmatrix} \begin{vmatrix} x_1 & y_1\\x_2 & y_2\end{vmatrix} &  \begin{vmatrix} y_1 & 1\\y_2 & 1\end{vmatrix} \\\\ \begin{vmatrix} x_3 & y_3\\x_4 & y_4\end{vmatrix} & \begin{vmatrix} y_3 & 1\\y_4 & 1\end{vmatrix} \end{vmatrix} }
{\begin{vmatrix} \begin{vmatrix} x_1 & 1\\x_2 & 1\end{vmatrix} &  \begin{vmatrix} y_1 & 1\\y_2 & 1\end{vmatrix} \\\\ \begin{vmatrix} x_3 & 1\\x_4 & 1\end{vmatrix} & \begin{vmatrix} y_3 & 1\\y_4 & 1\end{vmatrix} \end{vmatrix}}.
$$
By [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule), this means that $P_x,P_y$ solve the system of equations 
$$
\pmatrix{ \begin{vmatrix} x_1 & 1\\x_2 & 1\end{vmatrix} &  \begin{vmatrix} y_1 & 1\\y_2 & 1\end{vmatrix} \\\\ \begin{vmatrix} x_3 & 1\\x_4 & 1\end{vmatrix} & \begin{vmatrix} y_3 & 1\\y_4 & 1\end{vmatrix} } \pmatrix{P_y\\ -P_x} = 
\pmatrix{
 \begin{vmatrix} x_1 & y_1\\ x_2 & y_2\end{vmatrix}\\ \\
 \begin{vmatrix} x_3 & y_3\\x_4 & y_4\end{vmatrix}}
$$
which is to say that 
$$
\begin{vmatrix} x_1 & 1\\x_2 & 1\end{vmatrix} P_y -   \begin{vmatrix} y_1 & 1\\y_2 & 1\end{vmatrix} P_x = \begin{vmatrix} x_1 & y_1\\ x_2 & y_2\end{vmatrix}\\ 
\\ \phantom{1}\\
\begin{vmatrix} x_3 & 1\\x_4 & 1\end{vmatrix} P_y -  \begin{vmatrix} y_3 & 1\\y_4 & 1\end{vmatrix} P_x = \begin{vmatrix} x_3 & y_3\\x_4 & y_4\end{vmatrix}.
$$

Since other answers are appearing, I'll stop there.

Comment: So at the end, I am lost as to where the determinants as coefficients of $P_{y}$ and $P_{x}$ come from. I see how Cramers Rule is used at this point to get the end results (before you reverse engineered), but I do not now how the determinants arrived in the equations of a line prior to applying it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have that $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ determine the line $a_1 x+b_1 y+c_1=0$.

Now write $u_1:=(x_1,y_1,1)$ and $u_2:=(x_2,y_2,1)$, and $w_1:=(a_1,b_1,c_1)$.

Then we have $w_1 \cdot u_1 =0$ and $w_1 \cdot u_2 =0$. Hence $w_1$ is parallel to the cross product $u_1\wedge u_2$.

For the second line $a_2 x+b_2 y+c_2=0$ we have 
$u_3:=(x_3,y_3,1)$ and $u_4:=(x_4,y_4,1)$, and $w_2:=(a_2,b_2,c_2)$. Hence $w_2$ is parallel to $u_3\wedge u_4$.

The common point $(x,y)$ of the two lines is got by considering $p:=(x,y,1)$. We have that $w_1 \cdot p=0$ and $w_2 \cdot p=0$, so that $p$ is parallel to $w_1 \wedge w_2$.

That is $p=\lambda[ (x_1 \wedge x_2) \wedge (x_3 \wedge x_4)]$, where $\lambda$ is chosen to ensure the third component of $p$ is $1$.

If you use the usual expression for a cross-product as a triple of $2\times 2$ determinants you'll easily see where all the terms in the expression you reference come from.

Comment: You should state explicitly that $\wedge$ denotes the cross-product.

Comment: Why is the 3rd term $1$ for each vector?

Comment: Because I chose it to be so, to make the equation of the line hold at the two given points.